# How to allow PHP In WordPress text widget

Tags: php, widgets, widget-text

I want to add a text widget to my new WordPress website, but in the text widget there are some PHP snippets and I am finding it difficult to do it.

Please help me Guys.

Comment: please provide more specific details on what you are trying to do. especially where are the snippets, what are they, and what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you should consider using a shortcode.  This is exactly the problem that shortcodes try to solve.

By default, Widgets don't process shortcodes, but that can be easily changed.

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

This would allow you to use any shortcodes in the Widget text area.  Next would be to get the PHP code you want to run in a shortcode.

This can be done with the `add_shortcode()` function.  More details found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_tag', 'prefix_shortcode_tag' );
function prefix_shortcode_tag( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'foo' => 'no foo',
      'baz' => 'default baz'
    ), $atts ) );

    // your php code here
}
```

In the widget area, you can now use [shortcode_tag] and run the PHP code you want.

Comment: The combination TextWidget+Shortcode is quite powerful. Nice suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
function add_php_text($text) {
 if (strpos($text, '<' . '?') !== false) {
 ob_start();
 eval('?' . '>' . $text);
 $text = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 }
 return $text;
}

add_filter('widget_text', 'add_php_text', 99);
```

Add this code to your functions.php and all the text widgets can use PHP code as long as it goes in the  tags .

Comment: -1 because this will break anything that starts with <? even if it is not a proper php, it assumes that there is no text before or after the code.  It might be good enough for very specific usage pattern but not as a general solution.